# On the sigma algebra generated by the sum of two indipendent random variables (quick question).

Tags: probability-theory

Can't find this question with the independence assumption anywhere on mathstack:

Given two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, is it true that $\sigma(X) \subset \sigma(X+Y)?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli($1/2$), then the event $\{X=1\}$
cannot be obtained from the atoms $\{X+Y=0\}$, $\{X+Y=1\}$, $\{X+Y=2\}$ of $\sigma(X+Y)$.